# base64 encoding after sha1 encoding, why different results

Tags: openssl, base64, sha1

I try to execute these two command in shell, I think that the results should be the same, but are not.

(1)

```
echo -n 123456 | openssl sha1 -binary | base64
```

result:

> fEqNCco3Yq9h5ZUglD3CZJT4lBs=

(2)

```
echo -n 123456 | openssl sha1 | base64
```

result:

> KHN0ZGluKT0gN2M0YThkMDljYTM3NjJhZjYxZTU5NTIwOTQzZGMyNjQ5NGY4OTQxYgo=

I think input for comand 'base64' , should be same byte array.  why i get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding the result will tell you what's going on.

In the second case, the [decoded](https://www.base64decode.org/) Base64 string contains:

> (stdin)= 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b

So you get a hexadecimal string of the hash, instead of the binary value, plus the totally unwanted '(stdin)= ' on the beginning.

With `-binary` you get the wanted binary value.